# Treat nil as wildcard type

Tags: types, lisp, common-lisp, clos

I'm writing a Lisp program and am trying to be a bit conscientious about types. I guess there's performance improvements, but I'm more interested in using type annotations for documentation and safety. The problem is `nil`. I've run into two problems so far.

Exhibit A:

```
>(defmethod foo ((bar bar-class) (quux quux-class))
   ...)

>(foo (make-instance 'bar-class) nil)
 ERROR: No applicable method, etcetera etcetera, because nil is not of type quux-class
```

Exhibit B:

```
(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((f foo) &rest args)
  "Initialize the grid to be the right size, based on the height and width of the foo."
  (declare (ignorable args))
  (setf (slot-value f 'grid) (make-array (list (width f) (height f))
                                         :element-type 'foo-component
                                         :adjustable nil
                                         :initial-element nil)))

style-warning: 
  NIL is not a FOO-COMPONENT.
```

What's the best practice here? So far the only remotely-insightful idea I've had is to use the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and have `(defclass nil-quux-class (quux-class) ...)` and `(defclass nil-foo-component (foo-component) ...)`, but that seems hacky at best. I'm not sure *why*, but it does. Frankly I'm not used to design patterny workarounds in CLOS :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(A) What to you want to happen when you call `foo` with `nil` for the `quux`
argument?

If you want nothing at all to happen then

```
(defmethod foo ((bar bar-class) (quux null))
  nil)
```

will sort you out.

If you want the same code to be called as if you had passed an
instance of `quux-class`, then either:

```
(defmethod foo ((bar bar-class) (quux quux-class))
  (do-stuff bar quux))

(defmethod foo ((bar bar-class) (quux null))
  (do-stuff bar quux))
```

or:

```
(defmethod foo ((bar bar-class) quux)
  (unless (or (typep bar 'bar-class)
              (null bar))
    (error "Expected a bar-class or null, got ~s." quux))
  (do-stuff bar quux))
```

(B) You've gone

```
(make-array size :element-type 'foo-component
                 :initial-element nil)
```

and your lisp implementation has pointed out a contradiction - the
initial elements can't be both `nil` and `foo-component`s. (Well, I guess
that depends on what your type `foo-component` looks like. I'm assuming
it doesn't include `null`.)

You might consider:

```
(make-array :element-type '(or foo-component null)
            :initial-element nil)
```

but be aware: what do you want your lisp to gain from knowing that an
array will contain either `foo-component`s or `nil`s? Optimisation? Error
checking on your behalf? (Your mileage might vary, according to which
lisp implementation you're using.)

Comment: Thanks! A) I wasn't thrilled with duplicating code (calling do-stuff twice), but I guess it makes sense. And as the program grows I may very well want to handle `nil`s differently, which this'll let me do. B) Yes, I want error-checking. SBCL is pretty good about it.

Comment: OK. Btw I put in an edit for your call to make array (fixed parens & indents); I guess it'll show up in time...

Answer (score 4):

Note that the element-type to a `MAKE-ARRAY` is not a real type declaration. It's a hint to the Lisp implementation what kind of data the array should be able to store. It then might select specialized array implementations or not.

`UPGRADED-ARRAY-ELEMENT-TYPE` returns the element type of the most specialized array representation capable of holding items of the type denoted by typespec.

```
CL-USER 12 > (upgraded-array-element-type '(integer 0 100))
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 8)
```

Above means that I request an array with integer elements between 0 and 100. This Lisp (here LispWorks) will give me an array with element type `(unsigned-byte 8)`.

More examples:

```
CL-USER 13 > (upgraded-array-element-type 'fixnum)
(SIGNED-BYTE 64)

CL-USER 14 > (upgraded-array-element-type 'complex)
T

CL-USER 15 > (defclass foo-component () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO-COMPONENT 402030196B>

CL-USER 16 > (upgraded-array-element-type 'foo-component)
T
```

`T` here means that the array actually will store all kinds of data objects.

```
CL-USER 17 > (upgraded-array-element-type '(or null foo-component))
T

CL-USER 20 > (make-array 2
                         :element-type 'foo-component
                         :initial-element (make-instance 'foo-component))
#(#<FOO-COMPONENT 40203B9A03> #<FOO-COMPONENT 40203B9A03>)

CL-USER 21 > (array-element-type *)
T
```

Above shows that Lisp also then forgets, what was requested initially. We actually got an array of element-type `T` and when we ask for its element-type, then it is `T`.